# Any way to disable GitLab default metrics?

Tags: gitlab, prometheus, metrics

We literally don't have any of those things (Kubernetes, Nginx, HA proxy, AWS, ...) and all those default entries push down our own actual custom metrics:

[image]

I could not find any way to remove or disable those entries. We are running our own GitLab instance, with our own Prometheus server, and I have admin privileges on both.

Edit for clarification: I am talking about custom environment metrics, not metrics about GitLab itself. Our deploy targets don't use any of those technologies, and all the groups are empty when expanded.

Comment: Do you want to disable prometheus completely, if yes you can configure this in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file. The entry would look something like this, prometheus_monitoring['enable'] = false

Comment: I clarified the question (I hope), I'm not talking about monitoring GitLab itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to disable instrumentation completely with the method @Shantanu described you can configure Prometheus to drop metrics based on regex patterns. This way Prometheus will still scrape everything but delete matched metrics in the next step from its memory.

Here is an example how I did it with the default Grafana Loki metrics:

```yaml
  - job_name: loki
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["loki:3100"]
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__name__]
      regex: "(alertmanager|cortex|etcd|jaeger|prometheus|querier)_.*"
      action: drop
```

Comment: I clarified the question (I hope), I'm not talking about monitoring GitLab itself.